# SUMIF with VLOOKUP condition

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, sumifs

I'm trying to get a SUM of values where the NAME belongs to a specific COMPANY like Microsoft as shown in the example image below. Both Marc and Christian are from Microsoft and the sum of their values should be 115. Note the data will be in 3x different sheets as shown in the example.

I've tried a few different options, including using INDEX/MATCH but I can't figure it out. If anyone can lead me in the right direction I would be very thankful. I've done several searches and even watched videos about SUMIF/SUMIFS, VLOOKUP and INDEX/MATCH to see if I'm missing anything but no success.

[Spreadsheet here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HjQCYpryTP-06Aq8eWvigQnOFGpGnx7hRBCq1KUma-I/edit?usp=sharing)

[image]

Comment: =SUMIF(E2:E5,"Microsoft",B2:B5)

Comment: Thank you so much. I just noticed I forgot to mention that the data is in different sheets and lines so this formula wouldn't do the job.

Comment: Are structure same? 4 columns in order name, values, name company? Also you should update your question and include this dummy example with additional sheet

Comment: Unfortunately no, this is just a really simple example. I updated the question to say that the data will be in different sheets, thank you.

Comment: Include additional example sheet in your shared spreadsheet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Updated Answer:*

```js
=sum(ifna(filter(sumif(VALUES!A:A,COMPANIES!A:A,VALUES!B:B),COMPANIES!B:B=A2)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I edited the question to show that the data won't be aligned like shown in my first example. I definitely oversimplified it. The data will be in separate sheets and there will be name repetitions.

Comment: Updated the answer...

Answer (score 1):

Query() can help here.

If you just want a 'Microsoft' total, use:

```
=query({A:E},"select sum(Col2) where Col5 like 'Microsoft' label sum(Col2) '' ",0)
```

[image]

Otherwise, this will show totals for all companies:

```
=query({A:E},"select Col5,sum(Col2) where Col1 is not null group by Col5 label Sum(Col2) 'Total'",1)
```

[image]

For the updated, more complex question using different sheets, try:

```
=index(query({VALUES!A:B,iferror(vlookup(VALUES!A:A,COMPANIES!A:B,2,0),)},"select Col3,sum(Col2) where Col2 is not null group by Col3 label sum(Col2) 'TOTAL'",1))
```

[image]

If you want to order by TOTAL desc, then:

```
=index(query({VALUES!A:B,iferror(vlookup(VALUES!A:A,COMPANIES!A:B,2,0),)},"select Col3,sum(Col2) where Col2 is not null group by Col3 order by sum(Col2) desc label sum(Col2) 'TOTAL'",1))
```

Comment: Thank you, I edited the question to show that the data won't be aligned like shown in my first example. I definitely oversimplified it. The data will be in separate sheets and there will be name repetitions.

Comment: Solution updated.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. That worked and the only reason why I chose the other answer as solution is because it's more flexible and it would work better for what I'm doing, which is reporting on total usage of a specific tool. Regardless, your answer also works, thanks heaps.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Values and companies sheets are like in your example at current moment.

```
=let(z,hstack(values!B30:B38, map(values!A30:A38,lambda(x, xlookup(x,companies!A2:A7,companies!B2:B7,,0)))),arrayformula(sum(choosecols(z,1)*(choosecols(z,2)=A2))))
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Not a simple formula to decipher. I simply copy/pasted your formula but I'm getting an error "Function CHOOSE COLS parameter 2 value is 1. Valid values are between 0 and 0 inclusive." Any ideas?